# JavaScript function not working in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

HTML code for browse file button

```
<input type="file" multiple="false" accept="image/*" id="filein" onclick="filo()">
```

JavaScript

```
function filo(){ 
  var canin= document.getElementByID("c5");
  var imgin = document.getElementById("filein");
  var xct = canin.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image(filein);
  xct.drawImage(canin);
}
```

Comment: You've got a typo in `document.getElementByID("c5");`, it's `getElementById`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems.

- You need to use the `onchange` event not the `click` event

  `<input type="file" multiple="false" accept="image/*" id="filein">`

  You add the event listener using script rather than in line.

  `<script>  // this script must be place after the element filein or use an onload event.
      filein.onchange = filo();
  </script>`
- The function `getElementById` returns an element not a string. You need to get the filename (URL) from the element's `files` property
- Change the image construction as it does not take the image URL as an argument. You set the `img.src` to the url then wait for the image to load.
- The function `drawImage` function requires the image and at least 2 arguments that are the location to draw at.

Example of changes.

```
function filo () { 
    // Get the filename of the input element
    var imgin = document.getElementById("filein").files[0]; //  <<Get the file URL

    // Typo its getElementById not getElementByID
    var canin= document.getElementById("c5");
    var xct = canin.getContext("2d");

    // Image does not take a URL via the constructor
    var img = new Image();

    // set the URK here
    var img.src = imgin;

    // you need to wait for the image to load then you can draw it
    img.onload = function () {

       // drawImage function requires the image and at least 2 arguments 
       // that are the location to draw at    
       xct.drawImage(this, 0, 0); // this is the image in the onload event
    }
}
```